# DF-DFERH-01 Server Error when submitting in-app review

Tags: android, google-play

I am currently working on including in-app reviews into an app.
The in-app rating prompt does open as expected when triggered.
However, when I attempt to submit the review, I receive the following error: "Error while retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01", which causes the review to not end up in the Play Store (see Screenshot).
[Error displayed after submitting the in-app review](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0Ob8.jpg)

Some additional info:

1. The app is published to the Play Store as closed testing release.
2. I've tried several fixes that are suggested in order to solve this error, including:

- Clear Play Store data, force stop Play Store
- Uninstall updates in Play Store
- Clear Google Play Services data
- Clear Google Services Framework data
- Remove Google Account and re-add it

None of those have solved the issue so far.

Has anybody encountered this error in this context and would be able to suggest a solution?

Comment: Did you end up figuring out a solution?

Comment: did you find any solution? I'm also stuck at this. Although I'm testing the app in internal app sharing